# How do I use the PerformanceNavigationTiming API to track the duration of tasks across web workers and cross origin iframes?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am generating metrics on my web application by raising an event with a name and an associated absolute timestamp. These events are aggregated in a central repository of events that looks something like:

```js
const metricEvents = [
  { name: appStart, time: window.performance.timing.responseStart }
]

metricEvents.push({ name: 'interactive', time: new Date().getTime() })
```

I can then subtract the end time from the start time and obtain a duration for that task.

My web application makes use of Web Workers and cross origin iframes, all of which contribute metric events of their own.

Currently it's pretty simple for me to send absolute timestamps from the workers/frames and still calculate the durations of events from points (e.g. `A -> C` or `B -> E`).

I see that `PerformanceTiming` is deprecated in favour of `PerformanceNavigationTiming`. The issue is that `PerformanceNavigationTiming` gives back relative times relavent to the current entity (frame, worker, host). This means I am no longer able to use my existing approach to calculate the task times.

Instinctively I look to obtain an absolute timestamps from the new `PerformanceNavigationTiming` API, is that possible or is there a better way to approach this objective with the new API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Performance` object has a [`timeOrigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timeOrigin) property. You can use it to get absolute timings accross several contexts.

You can see [this example](https://w3c.github.io/hr-time/#example-2) from the specs which illustrate exactly your case.

Comment: But isn't the `timeOrigin` different for the original document loaded, an iFrame's document loading, and a Worker's initial load? (based upon this: https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#sec-time-origin)

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes they are all different, which is what we want, this value tells us to what other timings will be relative to. So they all point to the same time, but were all "snapshot" at different times (when the global life started). See https://w3c.github.io/hr-time/#example-2 for an example usage that fits almost exactly with OP's case. Basically, if you do `iframe.contentWindow.timeOrigin - performance.tiemOrigin` you'll get the time it took from current document's global creation to the iframe's global creation.

Comment: I interpreted the OP's question (specifically: "_obtain an absolute timestamp_") to mean a single (absolute) reference to measure all other metrics against. Or, a single (absolute) `timeOrigin` if you will rather than many across each context. Thanks for clarifying, but still don't know the intent of the question.

Comment: Sadly the `timeOrigin` property does not allow me to track a metric that starts on one context and ends in another (e.g. starts from worker and ends in iframe). Currently, using absolute timestamps allows me to push events to a central aggregate of all metric events then simply subtract the end event from the start event to generate a duration for my metric.

Comment: @RandyCasburn and with `timeOrigin` they have access to such an absolute timestamp, the origin one, which is the same wall-clock time for every context. You asked me if the timeOrigin was different for every context, it is, because they didn't start at the same time, but they all point to the same wall-clock time.

Comment: @DavidAlsh yes it does allow you to do this. You simply have to do in Worker `absoluteTimeFromWorker = timingFromWorker + self.performance.timeOrigin;` and in main `absoluteTimeFromMain = timingFromMain + window.performance.timeOrigin;` and now you can do whatever you want with these, they share the same base.

Comment: @Kaiido - thanks for taking time for clarification. (people don't say thank you enough on here to the volunteers who help so many!).